# Embedding Python via boost::python in a C++ Python extension

Tags: c++, python, embedding, extending

I have the following scenario: A custom C++ library should have Python embedded via boost::python. This library should get statically linked against different wrappers which allow the library to be used with the .NET framework, with other languages, as well as with Python itself.

In the case of wrapping the library so that it ends up being a Python C extension, will the fact that the library itself embeds the Python interpreter be a problem?

Additionally, what consequences could it have if the embedded Python version wouldn't match the version of the Interpreter importing the extension?

Kind regards,
Daniel